# Format list values to currency with list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to format values in list to currency using locale library and list comprehension.

```
p = [locale.currency([1,2,3,4], grouping=True) for item in [1,2,3,4]]
print(p)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
s = format('%%.%if' % digits, abs(val), grouping, monetary=True)
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'list'
```

How can I get the output of `p` to be $1.00, $2.00, $3.00, $4.00 ?

Comment: Did you mean: `[locale.currency(item, grouping=True) for item in [1,2,3,4]]` ?

Comment: That worked! Thank you